# How to Navigate user to Home Page after logging in LWR Site in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, login, experience-cloud, navigationmixin.navigate

I have experience cloud login page which uses LWC and custom Apex controller with system `site` class to perform login operations.

After successful login we get a `pageReference URL` back from `site` class.

Apex code:

```
 ApexPages.PageReference pageRef = Site.login(username, password, startUrl);

        if(pageRef != null){
             return pageRef.getUrl();
        }
```

LWC JS:

```
  import doLogin from '@salesforce/apex/APP_LoginController.doLogin';

  doLogin({ username: this.username, password: this.password })
        .then(result => {
```

**Below just refreshes page and sets it back to login page**

```
window.open(result, '_self');
```

**opens new tab and keeps login tab as is**

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                type: 'comm__namedPage',
                attributes: {
                    name: 'Home'
                }
            });
```

**keeps user on login page only**

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                type: 'standard__webPage',
                attributes: {
                    url: `${basePath}/redeemcredits/`
                }
            },
            true 
          );

        })
```

Once the user is logged in, how do I redirect the user to the experience cloud Home page in the same tab?

Comment: What's the question? Expected behavior? Actual behavior?

Comment: @sfdcfox Added the question at the end. Actual behavior is added in JS code.

How do I redirect the user after they are logged in to to Home page? NavigatioMixin is not working in LWR site for some reason.

Comment: `window.open(result, '_self');` should do the work. What is the value in `result` that you are getting, please debug and check it once.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl. Then use window.open to open in the same window.

```
    this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
        type: 'comm__namedPage',
                    attributes: {
                        name: 'Home'
                    }
    }).then(url => {
        window.open(url, "_self"); // this will replace the URL.
    });
```

Comment: I tried all different navigationMixin types including the above, it stays on the same page and refreshes the page but doesn't login.